# Linking Tbb library in already set up c++ code (via makefile) Mac OS system

Tags: c++, cmake, tbb, cmakelists-options

I'm trying to parallelize my code via TBB library, using the tool tbb::parallel_for. I use a Mac OS computer and I downloaded and installed Tbb with Homebrew.

The Tbb is in Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨opt⁩ ▸ ⁨intel⁩ ▸ ⁨compilers_and_libraries_2020.1.216⁩ ▸ ⁨mac⁩ ▸ ⁨tbb⁩ ▸ ⁨include⁩.

When I try to compile the following error appears:

```
  "tbb::interface5::internal::task_base::destroy(tbb::task&)", referenced from:
      tbb::flow::interface10::graph::~graph() in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_terminate()", referenced from:
      tbb::interface7::task_arena::terminate() in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_initialize()", referenced from:
      tbb::interface7::task_arena::initialize() in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::task_group_context::init()", referenced from:
      tbb::task_group_context::task_group_context(tbb::internal::string_index) in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::task_group_context::reset()", referenced from:
      tbb::flow::interface10::graph::wait_for_all() in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()", referenced from:
      tbb::flow::interface10::graph::~graph() in interface_stokes.cpp.o
      tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<unsigned long>, tbb::internal::parallel_for_body<main::$_0, unsigned long>, tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<unsigned long> const&, tbb::internal::parallel_for_body<main::$_0, unsigned long> const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)", referenced from:
      vtable for tbb::interface9::internal::flag_task in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id)", referenced from:
      tbb::internal::throw_exception(tbb::internal::exception_id) in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::internal::get_initial_auto_partitioner_divisor()", referenced from:
      tbb::interface9::internal::adaptive_mode<tbb::interface9::internal::auto_partition_type>::adaptive_mode() in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_execute(tbb::interface7::internal::delegate_base&) const", referenced from:
      void tbb::interface7::task_arena::execute_impl<void, tbb::flow::interface10::graph::wait_functor const>(tbb::flow::interface10::graph::wait_functor const&) in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::task_group_context::is_group_execution_cancelled() const", referenced from:
      tbb::flow::interface10::graph::wait_for_all() in interface_stokes.cpp.o
      tbb::task::is_cancelled() const in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      tbb::interface9::internal::allocate_sibling(tbb::task*, unsigned long) in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::free(tbb::task&) const", referenced from:
      operator delete(void*, tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy const&) in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      operator new(unsigned long, tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy const&) in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::free(tbb::task&) const", referenced from:
      operator delete(void*, tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy const&) in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      operator new(unsigned long, tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy const&) in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "typeinfo for tbb::task", referenced from:
      typeinfo for tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<unsigned long>, tbb::internal::parallel_for_body<main::$_0, unsigned long>, tbb::auto_partitioner const> in interface_stokes.cpp.o
      typeinfo for tbb::interface9::internal::flag_task in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  "vtable for tbb::task", referenced from:
      tbb::task::task() in interface_stokes.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [apps/interface_stokes/interface_stokes] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/interface_stokes/CMakeFiles/interface_stokes.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

To compile my work (saved in a different folder than TBB) I use a Cmakelists, in which I have add:

```
#Additional modules path for cmake
set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
     ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

include(safeguards)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-std=c++14 -g -fpermissive -fsanitize=address")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-std=c++14 -O3 -mavx -g -fpermissive")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASEASSERT "-std=c++14 -O3 -mavx -g -fpermissive")



find_package(TBB)
if (TBB_FOUND)
  include_directories(${TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(LINK_LIBS ${LINK_LIBS} ${TBB_LIBRARIES})
  set(HAVE_INTEL_TBB TRUE)
endif()



include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

include_directories(src)
include_directories(contrib)
add_subdirectory(apps)
add_subdirectory(tests)
add_subdirectory(output)
```

In my program, there is also another folder, named cmake, in which there are some files .cmake, that actually I don't know their purposes.

I've never studied this subject and I 'm working on an already built-up code. I guess that the error is due to a bad linking of my code and the Tbb library.
Does someone know how to fix it?
Thank you so much in advance
Stefano

Comment: I guess you need [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: I solved the problem! Actually was enough to add in Cmakelists ``` set(-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="<path_to_root_tbb>") ``` Thank you very much as well Evg!!!! I solved the problem thanks to your link!

Comment: Nice to hear that. ;)